# Error while creating a new customer via BCS from within a web part

Tags: web-part, bcs

This is my first time that I am using BCS via a web part and in general.

this is my code and I am getting the following error: 
**The given dot notation 'CustomerID' refers to a node in Type Descriptor structure that does not exist.**

valueDictionary["CustomerID"] = CustomerID.Text; <-- I get Error here.

Anyone has any idea how to solve it or has any suggestions?

```
protected void btnInsertNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (new SPServiceContextScope(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site)))
                {
                    // Get the BDC service and metadata catalog.
                    BdcService service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<BdcService>(String.Empty);
                    IMetadataCatalog catalog = service.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(SPServiceContext.Current);

                    // Get the entity using the specified name and namespace.
                    IEntity entity = catalog.GetEntity(EntityNamespace, EntityName);
                    ILobSystemInstance LobSysteminstance = entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;

                    // Get the fields on the entity.
                    IView createView = entity.GetCreatorView("CreateCustomer");
                    IFieldValueDictionary valueDictionary = createView.GetDefaultValues();

                    // Set the values of the entity fields.
                    valueDictionary["CustomerID"] = CustomerID.Text; <-- I get Error here. it seems something is wrong with the code above.
                    valueDictionary["CompanyName"] = CompanyName.Text
                    valueDictionary["ContactName"] = ContactName.Text;
                    valueDictionary["ContactTitle"] = ContactTitle.Text;
                    valueDictionary["Address"] = Address.Text;
                    valueDictionary["City"] = City.Text;
                    valueDictionary["Region"] = Region.Text;
                    valueDictionary["PostalCode"] = PostalCode.Text;
                    valueDictionary["Country"] = Country.Text;
                    valueDictionary["Phone"] = Phone.Text;
                    valueDictionary["Fax"] = Fax.Text;

                    // Call the creator method and display the returned
                    // Customer ID.
                    Identity id = entity.Create(valueDictionary, LobSysteminstance);

                    DossierID.Text = id.GetIdentifierValues().GetValue(0).ToString();


                    StatusLabel.Text = "Customer successfully created.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                StatusLabel.Text = "Unable to create customer." + ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

Here are the parameters:

```
<Parameters>
                <Parameter Direction="In" Name="CustomerID">
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" LobName="CustomerID" CreatorField="true" IdentifierName="CustomerId" Name="CustomerId" DefaultDisplayName="CustomerID" />
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter Direction="In" Name="CompanyName">
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" CreatorField="true" Name="CompanyName" />
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter Direction="In" Name="ContactName">
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" CreatorField="true" Name="ContactName" />
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter Direction="In" Name="ContactTitle">
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" CreatorField="true" Name="ContactTitle" />
                </Parameter>
```

..

Comment: Have you checked that "CustomerID" property is properly written in the Type Descriptor/entity?

Comment: Hi Alex, that's a good question but how do I check that?

Comment: you have a custom bcs solution that you created?

Comment: I created in via SharePoint designer. I simply created a wcf and added it as BCS in SPD.

Comment: Alex, I think I got it what you meant. I opened the bdcm file and I checked the TyperDescriptor. What I see her is that it is read only. Probably that is blocking it. 
<TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" ReadOnly="true" IdentifierName="CustomerID" Name="CustomerID">

Comment: Eventhough I removed the readOnly i am still getting the error above.

Comment: I removed valueDictionary["CustomerID"] = CustomerID.Text; from my code and now it goes through eventhough I get another error. For the time being let's solve the first problem.

Comment: Yes that's what i meant,have you also checked in your parameter configuration?
here's a pic:
http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SDxNQGpww6E/S1dHK-NXkxI/AAAAAAAABcU/P-hqRHa-zwM/s1600/image95.png

Comment: Alex, thanks for your help. I should had seen it from start. In my code I type CustomerID instead of CustomerId, ..id in lower letters. it is solved now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would apritiate you mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your parameter configuration ,here's a pic:

[image]

Comment: Alex, one more thing. I am using Customers table in Northwind database as example. Customers table has only two columns that do not allow null, CustomerID and CompanyName. Now, when I try to insert a new row into Customers Table via BCS and I supply a value for both columns, but not for the rest of the columns, BCS complains that I have not supplied the values for the rest of the columns. Why do I have to supply a value for all columns? How can i suppress this error and allow insertion of a new row but supplying only values for those columns that are required? Thanks again

Comment: this is strange, I have never got this kind of error